# how to change minimum test pass percentage from 100 to 50 in azure devops to continue the build?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

how to change minimum test pass percentage from 100 to 50 in azure devops to continue the build ?
we want to continue build if test pass percentage is more than 50 and fails the build if pass percentage is less than 50%.